# How to match non-ASCII (German, Spanish, etc.) letters in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I was unable to find or create a regex which match only letters,spaces, accented letters and spanish and german letters.

I'm using this for now:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[a-z _]*$");
```

I've tried:

```
^[:alpha: _]*$   
^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*$  
^[-\p{L}]*$
```

Any idea? Or the regex supported by javascript engines are limited?

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd to last case looks like it should work, but is missing a " " and "_":

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*$/.test("aäöüÄÖÜz")` => true in FF 3.6 and IE8

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*$/.test("é")` => false in FF 3.6 and IE8

I'm am unable to find the other constructs in [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf).

Happy coding.

**Edit** Also check the page encoding and make sure it is "unicode" (UTF-8 likely). If this can't be ensured, then use the `\uXXXX` escape sequences in the regular expression (using the escapes can be done anyway and may help with source code editing/control).

Answer (score 1):

I'm parsing a name input field, and this seems to be working for both German and French:

`^[a-zA-Z\-ÀàÂâÆæÇçÈèÉéÊêËëÎîÏïÔôŒœÙùÛûÜü]*$`

Some folks have names like 'Rölf-Dieter', and this lets them through, while checking for numbers. A little extreme, but it works!