# JavaScript not recognizing regular expression classes

Tags: javascript, regex

### Original question

I seem to have trouble seeing the obvious. I'm trying to use [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) in JavaScript. They *are* supported in JavaScript, [aren't they](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907275/regular-expression-to-match-brackets)?

If I type this in a console, I get the following result.

```
var s = "test string-banane. Aber bitte mit Sahne! 12 Stück, um genau zu sein. 12 Stück Sahne.";
console.log( s.replace(/[:alnum:]/g, "_") );

"test stri_g-b____e. Aber bitte _it S_h_e! 12 Stück, __ ge___ z_ sei_. 12 Stück S_h_e."
```

It reads the square brackets too literally!

Compare this to the following variation, which is rather what I'm trying to achieve (except, that method fails to cover German umlauts and stuff):

```
console.log( s.replace(/[0-9a-zA-Z]/g, "_") );

"____ ______-______. ____ _____ ___ _____! __ __ü__, __ _____ __ ____. __ __ü__ _____."
```

Using double brackets [[:alnum:]] doesn't seem to help either. That doesn't replace anything at all!

I'd appreciate it if you could help me – or point me to a solved duplicate thread. (I did use the search, though …)

### Edit

Using [this online tool](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) to find the required Unicode ranges, I managed to figure out what I need. This covers German umlauts, French accents and probably more … I hope this will suffice.

```
var s = "test string-banane. Aber bitte mit Sahne! 12 Stück, um genau zu sein. 12 Stück ~Sahne. Voilá, alors dans l'ecole. Avec Louis de Funès. Hoëcker, Sie sind raus! Ceçille.";
s.replace( /[0-9a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF]/g, "_" );

"____ ______-______. ____ _____ ___ _____! __ _____, __ _____ __ ____. __ _____ ~_____. _____, _____ ____ _'_____. ____ _____ __ _____. _______, ___ ____ ____! _______."
```

Thanks!

Comment: They're not supported.

Comment: You can put all characters you need in the regex. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343144/how-to-match-non-ascii-german-spanish-etc-letters-in-regex

Comment: Apparently, Javascript does not implement/support POSIX character classes. There is a very comprehensive answer on this thread on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode

Comment: @elclanrs, That's the thing. I don't know what characters to expect. And I don't know what *not* to expect so I can exclude them.

Comment: @rla4, Thanks, that links is more useful than it looks on first sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&p=4370095

I can't speak to whether it will work for your needs or not and it's very, very verbose. But if you have a critical need to do the matching, it seems to work better than anything built in (for instance, it works on your example):

```
var s = "test string-banane. Aber bitte mit Sahne! 12 Stück, um genau zu sein. 12 Stück Sahne.";
console.log( s.replace(/[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u0523\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0621-\u064A\u066E-\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5-\u06E6\u06EE-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4-\u07F5\u07FA\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0972\u097B-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0-\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C59\u0C60-\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE1\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D28\u0D2A-\u0D39\u0D3D\u0D60-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32-\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2-\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDD\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8B\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065-\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC\u1100-\u1159\u115F-\u11A2\u11A8-\u11F9\u1200-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u1676\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F0\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19A9\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE-\u1BAF\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u2094\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2C6F\u2C71-\u2C7D\u2C80-\u2CE4\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D30-\u2D65\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31B7\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400\u4DB5\u4E00\u9FC3\uA000-\uA48C\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A-\uA62B\uA640-\uA65F\uA662-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA697\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78C\uA7FB-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAC00\uD7A3\uF900-\uFA2D\uFA30-\uFA6A\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]/g, "_") );

____ ______-______. ____ _____ ___ _____! 12 _____, __ _____ __ ____. 12 _____ _____.
```

But again, it's super-duper long because it specifies all the unicode "letters" and "numbers" that the creator could find (though seems to skip ASCII numbers, so you might need to toss those in).

Without native support in ECMAScript, this might be the best you're going to get. Sorry!

Comment: Wow, that *is* really long! (^^; ) — What I figured out is similar but way more compact. Probably not as sophisticated but it does meet my low requirements. Let me edit the OP and show you.